# How to check if the validator validated and failed validation on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have multiple validators on the page that all work properly when the Submit button is clicked

However, I need to check if the validators have failed when I initiate a postback through a dropdown selected index changed event so that the failed validation messages properly persist stay

In other words I am trying to check if the certain validator has been just fired and failed

I tried the following

1. I checked the isValid property, but it is always true no matter what
2. I tried to check Page.IsValid method but it fails without the previous 
   Page.Validate() call
3. I tried to check if the failed message is visible and present but there no 
   such option for the validator

Thus, is there a way to check if the required validator was just fired and failed?

It seems to be something simple but I still can't find a solution

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Besides suggesting calling  `Page.Validate()` it is hard to tell, could you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with a solution

HTML

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel1">
    <ContentTemplate>

    <table class="innerTable" border="0">
      <tr>
    <td>
        <asp:DropDownList  CssClass="textboxwidth" runat="server" ID="ddOrg" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddOrg_SelectedIndexChanged" setCausesValidation="true"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator SetFocusOnError="true" ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="ddOrg" InitialValue="" ErrorMessage="* Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <input type="hidden" id="hdFirmValidator" runat="server" />
        <input type="hidden" id="hdPhoneValidator" runat="server" />
        <input type="hidden" id="hdPhoneValidatorRegex" runat="server" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtOrgOther" Enabled="false" CssClass="textboxwidth" MaxLength="100" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator SetFocusOnError="true" ID="RequiredFieldValidator12" Enabled="false" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtOrgOther" ErrorMessage="* Required" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:TextBox CssClass="textboxwidth" ID="txtOrgAddress" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator SetFocusOnError="true" ID="RequiredFieldValidator14" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtOrgAddress" ErrorMessage="* Required" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:TextBox CssClass="textboxwidth" ID="txtOrgPhone" runat="server" MaxLength="30"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator SetFocusOnError="true" ID="RequiredFieldValidator15" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtOrgPhone" ErrorMessage="* Required" ></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="regexPhone1" ValidationExpression="^.{0,30}" ErrorMessage="*Enter upto 30 digit phone number" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtOrgPhone"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</td>
              </tr>
       </table>
</ContentTemplate>
```

JavaScript

```
    window.onload = function () {

    var btnSubmit = document.getElementById("<%=btnSubmit.ClientID%>");
    function SetHiddenFields() {

    var firmValidator = document.getElementById("<%=RequiredFieldValidator14.ClientID%>");
    var hdFirmValidator = document.getElementById("<%=hdFirmValidator.ClientID%>");
    hdFirmValidator.value = firmValidator.style.display;

    var phoneValidator = document.getElementById("<%=RequiredFieldValidator15.ClientID%>");
    var hdPhoneValidator = document.getElementById("<%=hdPhoneValidator.ClientID%>");
    hdPhoneValidator.value = phoneValidator.style.display;

    var phoneValidatorRegEx = document.getElementById("<%=regexPhone1.ClientID%>");
    var hdPhoneValidatorRegex = document.getElementById("<%=hdPhoneValidatorRegex.ClientID%>");
    hdPhoneValidatorRegex.value = phoneValidatorRegEx.style.display;

    return true;

}

btnSubmit.onclick = SetHiddenFields; }
```

Codebehind

```
    protected void ddOrg_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Srver side code

        RequiredFieldValidator3.Validate();

        if (hdFirmValidator.Value != string.Empty)
        {
            RequiredFieldValidator14.Validate();
        }

        if (hdPhoneValidator.Value != string.Empty)
        {
            RequiredFieldValidator15.Validate();
        }

        if (hdPhoneValidatorRegex.Value != string.Empty)
        {
            regexPhone1.Validate();
        }

    }
```